# Short story predicting online shopping and no one going outside anymore

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, prediction

I remember reading this short story when I was a child in the 1970s. I'm thinking it was in the Houghton Mifflin readers.

Story was everyone didn't go out on the streets because of over crowding and bought everything through their televisions. A couple of kids snuck out and there was no one on the streets.

Has anyone heard this one? Anyone know the author?

Answer (score 2):

Some elements are similar to the Asimov story "[It's Such a Beautiful Day](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62723)".

Hits:

- No one ever goes outside.
- A kid accidentally does, and likes it. There is no one else outside.
- Story is old enough to be read in the 1970s (first appeared 1954).

Misses:

- The technology that keeps everyone indoors is portal transportation,
  not TV shopping or overcrowding.
- No explicit shopping at home; trips to the store are done via portal.